# Python: Pulling data from JSON Using an API, Sending to Excel. Getting Type Error: NoneType Object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, json, excel, loops

New with pyhton and APIs, but I am trying to collect a large amount of data from a server using an API. Script was working up until today, when I came across the Type error for NoneType. Did a print of the data in a for loop to see where it crapped out at. Found the culprit, now I am trying to figure out how to skip over it, or place a default value.

For most of the data I get the following key and value from the JSON file:

item:
  0:
   data:
       key: value
       key: value
       key: value

But for a couple of specific items in the JSON I get the follow:

item:
  0:
   data:
       key: []

How do I force my script to skip this specific key, or at least give it a default value rather than killing the program and stopping the process from writing to excel due to the TypeError?

```
for entry in search["items"]:
    info = entry['data']['info']
    info1 = entry['data']["info"]
    info2 = entry['data']["info"]
    info3 = entry['data']["info"]
    info5 = entry['data']["info"]
    info6= entry['data']["info"]
    info7= entry['data']["info"]
    info8= entry['data']["info"]
    info9= entry['type']
    info10= entry["subscription"]['info']
    info11= entry["subscription"]["info"]
    info12= entry["uid"]
    info13= entry["subscription"]["info"]
    info14= entry["info"]
    info15= entry['gateway']["info"]
    info16= entry['gateway']["info"]
    info17= entry['gateway']["info"]
    info18= entry['labels']
    info19= entry['info']
    a = int(last_comm or 0)/1000.0
    r = (datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(a).strftime
         ('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    last_sync = entry["lastSyncDate"]
    b = int(last_sync or 0)/1000.0
    t = (datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(b).strftime
         ('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    webbrowser.open(av + uid + av_end + company)
    count +=1
    print(f"Site Name: {siteName}\n\ninfo: {info}\tinfo2: {info2} \t"
            f"info1: {info1}\tField: {info3}\n\n"
            f"Field: {info4}\t"
            f"Field: {info}\tField: {signal}\n"
            f"Field: {fw}\nField: {device}\nField: {t}\n"
            f"Field: {SIM}\tField: {mdn}\nField: {uid}\n"
            f"Field: {ipAdd}\nField: {commStat}\n"
            f"Field: {serialNumber}\n"
            f"Field: {macAdd}\nField: {r}\n"
            f"Field: {imei}\n")
```

Error comes up as this:

info10= entry["subscription"]['info']

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: can you add example about your json file??

Comment: why not add a try except block, when u catch the exception u can assign the default value.

Comment: What you're trying to do here is called "error handling". You should google "try except python" to see how you could create code that would try to do something with the JSON data, but do something else in the event it runs into the type of error you're experiencing.

Comment: why are you making multiple variables which contain the same data, I am confused...

Comment: the example of my code is just place holders. I am using an API call to get a bunch of data for about 500 unique devices. So each of those fields would represent specific data I want apart of my spreadsheet.

Comment: @LetEpsilonBeLessThanZero That worked, had to add it to each subscription entry, and now it prints all the data to my spreadsheet. Only problem is it seems to be skipping the devices with no subscription data, rather than printing the default value into that excel field, but I can manage, just happy it works now. Thanks to everyone that responded,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add try, except block to the specific function with the problem.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

So if the problem is with this field
`info2 = entry['data']["info"]`

then you would have to rewrite it as

```
info1 = entry['data']["info"]
try:
    info2 = entry['data']["info"]
except TypeError:
    info2 = 0
info3 = entry['data']["info"]
info5 = entry['data']["info"]
```

But really you need to learn more about data structures and repeaters so you don't have to repeat yourself in code so much. Its hard to say how to improve that without the actual data set.

Comment: Awesome, just tried this also and it provides the solution I needed. Much appreciated.